# Displaying Matplotlib Line Graph in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I'm working on taking some data from a dataset and plotting certain aspects of it. Here's my code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df1 = pd.read_csv('dataset_1.csv')
soil_moisture = list(df1.Soil_Moisture)
soil_temperature = list(df1.Soil_Temp)
print(len(soil_moisture))
print(len(soil_temperature))
plt.plot([soil_moisture], [soil_temperature])
plt.show()
```

As you can see, it takes data from each of those columns and tries to make a line graph. However, when I run, it just displays an empty graph. This is weird since when I print the soil_moisture and soil_temperature, it tells me that there's actual data, and none of my other plots in the same notebook are experiencing this. All help is appreciated!

[Here's an image of the jupyter output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZinG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please revise line 7 of your code as:

```
plt.plot(soil_moisture, soil_temperature)
```

When you use [soil_moisture] that means you are generating another list with list soil_moisture as its first element.